# Save content of an HTML comment

Tags: php, html, strpos

I have a page and i wanted to save the comment of an html comment as a variable:

```
<!--http://localhost/sfddsf.png-->
```

How do i only get the content of the html comment? I searched for a couple of answers but it's not working.

```
function getCurrentUrl(){
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $url = "http://" . $domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $url;
}
$html = getCurrentUrl();
$content = substr($html, strpos($html, "-->"), strpos($html, "<--"));
print_r( $content);
```

Comment: I guess I'm not real sure what your code is meant to do, but I don't see how it's been given anything other than a URL itself to parse? See: http://codepad.org/vVo5TvIC Note, I turned the `$_SERVER` references to strings only as a demo. But that's not an HTML comment it's returning.

Comment: Maybe you should try: `$content = getCurrentUrl();`

Answer (score 2):

I know a lot of people rag on regular expressions, but they might come in handy here. Try something like:

```
    $html = '<!--http://localhost/sfddsf.png-->';

    preg_match('/<!--([\S]+)-->/', $html, $matches);
    if ($matches[1])
       $url = $matches[1]; // should be http://localhost/sfddsf.png
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hey, nothing wrong with a bit of regex. Although I must ask why you are putting the `\S` in a character class.

Comment: Mainly because I'm not an expert on regex, and it seemed the shortest way to go. If I were actually doing this, I would use a more strict regex that makes sure it's actually a URL, but this seemed fine as far as examples go.

Comment: I don't rag on regex, it's a great tool. But not for parsing html.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$start = strpos($html, "<!--");
$end = strpos($html, "-->") + 3;
$content = substr($html, $start, $end - $start);
```

?

Or if you don't want the `<!--` and the `-->`, and a clean string, you can do:

```
$start = strpos($html, "<!--") + 4;
$end = strpos($html, "-->");
$content = trim(substr($html, $start, $end - $start));
```

Comment: That said, I do agree with Jemaclus on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confused:

1. You have the strings you're searching for backwards; using [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), it should be `haystack, start position, length`.
2. You're searching for the wrong opening tag (`"<!--"` instead of `-->`), and their position in the argument list is reversed from what it should be (`start, length` instead of `last, first` as it appears you have).
3. You're not searching anything that even approximates an html tag with the return value of `getCurrentUrl()`.

The below, however, works. Also note, however, this will not work if there are multiple html comments in your markup you're searching.

```
<?php

$html = "
<html>
<head>
<!--http://localhost/sfddsf.png-->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
";

echo "$html\n";
$strstart = strpos($html, "<!--") + 4;
$strend = strpos($html, "-->") - $strstart;
echo "$strstart, $strend\n";
$content = substr($html, $strstart, $strend);
print($content);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/3STPRsoj

Which prints:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--http://localhost/sfddsf.png-->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

22, 27
http://localhost/sfddsf.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse html with regex. Use xpath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query("//comment()") as $comment){
    echo $comment->nodeValue."\n";
}
```